# One search box against multiple views? MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working my way around MVC4 with a bit of bootstrap & Jquery, all technologies I'm relatively new to.

I want to have a view, containing X amount of partial views (In this case it's 4) with one search form that will query the active partial views table (Each partial view contains a table of data).

Here is my cshtml for my main view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "get",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "CustDetails"
                }))
{
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="AssetTabs" >
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#CustDetails">Customer Details</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Locations">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Assets">Assets</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#SSAs">SSAs</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content", id="taaaab">
    <div id="CustDetails" class="tab-pane fade in active">
       @Html.Action("CustomerDetailsView")
    </div>

    <div id="Locations" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Html.Action("LocationsView")
    </div>

    <div id="Assets" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Html.Action("AssetsView")
    </div>

    <div id="SSAs" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Html.Action("SsaView")
    </div>

</div>
```

that views controller methods relevant to this.

```
 public ActionResult CustomerDetailsView(string searchterm = null)
        {
            var model = QueryFetch.FetchCustData(CurrentID).Where(r => searchterm == null || r.Site_Name.ToLower().Contains(searchterm.ToLower()));

            return PartialView("_CustomerDetails", model);
        }

        public ActionResult LocationsView()
        {

            return PartialView("_Locations");
        }

        public ActionResult AssetsView()
        {
            return PartialView("_Assets");
        }

        public ActionResult SsaView(string searchterm = null)
        {

            var connection = QueryFetch.FetchSSAData();
          //  var connection = QueryFetch.FetchSSAData(CurrentID).Where(r => searchterm == null || r.ContractName.ToLower().Contains(searchterm.ToLower()));
            //return View(connection);
            return PartialView("_Ssa", connection);
        }
```

And finally here's what one of the partial views look like, they're all relatively related in terms of code:

```
@model IEnumerable<BL.vRP_CustomerData>




@*<h2> CustomerDetailsPartialView</h2>*@

<h1 id="YEMA"> No text located</h1>

<table class="table table-striped" id="CustDetailsTable">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Customer Name: @item.Site_Name</h4>
                        <br />

                        <div>SSAs active: @item.CountSSAs</div>
                        <div>SSAs near renewal: @item.CountSSANearRenewal</div>
                        <div>County : @item.Site_County</div>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit Customer</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit SSA</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit Locations</button>
                    </div>

                    <br /><br />
                    <div>Next renewal date: @item.NextSSARenewalDate</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I'm using bootstraps nav-tabs. I've been told to use Ajax, but I don't really know how to tackle it. How can I go by binding the search bar to the most active tab? I've looked around online for information related to the solution, but can't really apply it to my project.

Cheers guys and if I'm not being clear on anything do let me know and I'll try my best to clear it all out for you. Also, I am aware that my ajax request has a target id to "custdetails". This is the ID for my table in one of my views, rather it is older less relevant code, I know this is incorrect, hence why I'm asking you bunch of brains for some advice! :)

Cheers,

Jack

Comment: There is no one Search for all thing from the initial view. In order, to achieve this, you need to update the target when you change tabs. Hook for the tab selection changed and update the target when switch.